# Converting speedometer gear signal

Tags: hall-effect

This was a board which taken out from speedometer. At first the speedometer was cable type and the display was in digital.
I'm planning to convert the cable type speed into electronic one which consist of 3-wire because the original one had worn out on its cable housing. Looking on the board inside the speedometer itself had 4 point connected into converter circuit.

I already measured between these 4 point which relatively low voltage (1.2 V something) and in ohms there are two points were shorted, assuming it was connected.

As I planned to convert into electronic type instead cable ones, do this possible? Also what kind of component on U2 location? I'm attaching also the electric type of speedo gear that uses wire to send signal instead cable that I'm going to convert.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out this duplicate: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/85211/10976

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3jjb5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. What you've got (probably).*

It looks like the old system used a mechanical cable from the wheel to turn a slotted disc in the slotted photo sensor. It consists of an infrared (IR) LED (which is where you measured the 1.2 V) and a photo-transistor. The photo-transistor will turn on when IR light reaches it.

You will need to provide the right voltage to your sensor and connect the correct wire to the PCB on one side or other of Q1.

Your fourth photo (you should give them captions with numbers so we can discuss them without confusion) shows four slots in the rotating disc. That means that you will have gotten four pulses per revolution of the cable. If your new sensor does not give the same number of pulses per revolution then the displayed speed will be wrong.

Unfortunately you have not provided a circuit for the speedo board and have not provided a datasheet for the new sensor so further help is not possible.

Comment: yes, exactly.. kindly do refer edited photos, there are types of disc sitting under the U2.. so assuming this is not a hall effect or magnetic?

Comment: Is there something you do not understand about my answer?

Comment: Yes i understood, finally giving idea what is the really method were working on this type of speedometer. Great answer

Answer (score 0):

**U2 has E for "light" Emitter diode  and D for phototransistor Detector.** It is an optical slot with external rotating path to block IR light. A DMM will show 1.1V for positive Vf on emitter and low resistance with V+ on detector only when 10 mA or so flows thru + on emitter , otherwise high impedance.  **The Transistor also has a pin called (current) Emitter which is not to be confused with Light Emitter E, nor is the Light Detector D to be confused with the Diode.**

**These types of  logic or [transistor](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/optical-sensors-photointerrupters-slot-type-transistor-output/548?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAusQA4AuUIAykwE4CWAdgOYgAvsQC0AJmQg0kLgFcipCiACsdISJCTIlXNhJMABN051iANincAJq1FgqERi0ggQxJgE8G%2BVplxoGkA) optical interrupters in stock are shown here**.  These all have similar input current to output resistance (Rce=Vce/Ic) specs while the logic output types are CMOS Gates.

Original types used a cable to drive a rotating magnetic field voltage generator, which without a significant load current is kV/RPM  and may be scaled by to a DMM to read volts as RPM.

Similar types can use the frequency of a 1 pulse per rev signal to trigger a simple 1-shot RC circuit to generate an average voltage that increases with f and again be measured easily on DMM.

Alternatively you can take a Tach or speedometer from a Motorcycle or car and do the same and mount it on your bike, using recycled parts from the junkyard with any kind of magnetic, optical or mechanical sensor.

From one of my former fave employees, [Mr. Whizzard.](https://scontent.fykz1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.18169-9/21231316_1217155308391133_3517332444015978314_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_ohc=TViYnbehBIMAX-xb8N2&tn=uHB6ceN2OUA41bCi&_nc_ht=scontent.fykz1-1.fna&oh=442aeabe4b3f5da075a2a23ddf6ee5b7&oe=61596BD6)
[image]

Ask [him](http://www.mrwhizard.com/?fbclid=IwAR0JmQPtfL4lEezF1hXEnX4yW12Wr3B3lzlEK76jeFzClDAgNM8OrMQZOEI) for a better solution and say hi to him for me.

Comment: so do converting to the new speedogear type (which by tapping the wire into BGWR on board) doesn't work? the reason is because i wanted to get rid of that old type cable.

Comment: How did you simulate speed with the optical slot path ? and measure it? Was it damaged after working OK, or never worked  or damaged by reversing cable or what?

Comment: RGBW is only for three display LED Red Green Blue White, not the tach.

Comment: I simulate the speed on speedometer by connecting using a bit and a drill to fit into the worn cable housing.. the speed were running but because the cable housing were loose and no longer to fit tiny speedo cable brings me to think to get rid the cable speedo into some speedo with electric signal wire as I show the new one in the post to be combined with original speedometer if it were possible.

Comment: These are not compatible

Comment: Great thanks for the answer! It makes me clear about the actual working principle of this speedometer. Now,I have to find out a way to fix that worn out speed cable housing to make it working again.